react big calander onNavigate solution
I have modified react-big-calander load events specifically for time ranage when onNavigate triggers. Now it's not navigating to specific date when trying to navigate by clicking date header in month view it is reloading back in to month view. It is happening because of onNavigate is changing the date when triggering onNavigate.Is there any workaround for this. I wasn't able to find any other props that related to date header.
This is my calendar component :
<MyCalendar
     dayPropGetter={this.dayPropGetter}
     localizer={localizer}
     selectable
     events={this.state.eventData}
     startAccessor="EventDate"
     endAccessor="EndDate"
     eventPropGetter={this.eventStyleGetter}
     onSelectSlot={this.onSelectSlot}
     components={{
               event: this.renderEvent
                 }}
     onSelectEvent={this.onSelectEvent}
     defaultDate={this.state.selectedDate}
      views={{
       day: true,
       week: true,
       month: true,
       agenda: true,
       work_week: Year
              }}
        defaultView= {this.state.currentView}
        messages={
                  {
                      'today': strings.todayLabel,
                      'previous': strings.previousLabel,
                      'next': strings.nextLabel,
                      'month': strings.monthLabel,
                      'week': strings.weekLabel,
                      'day': strings.dayLable,
                            'showMore': total => `+${total} ${strings.showMore}`,
                            'work_week': strings.yearHeaderLabel
                          }
                        }
                        onNavigate={(date, view) => {
                          this.startDateCal(date, view);
                          console.log('date', date, 'view', view);
                        }}
                        onView={(view) => this.startDateCal(this.state.selectedDate, view)}
                        onShowMore={() => {this.setState({ currentView: 'day' });}}
        />
    

And this how I fetch events based on view and next previous month according to onNavigate.
private async startDateCal(date: Date, view: string) {

  this.setState({ isloading: true });
  
  if (view === 'month') {
    this.startDate = moment(date).startOf('month').toDate();
    this.endDate = moment(date).endOf('month').toDate();
    this.setState({ currentView: 'month' });
    this.setState({ selectedDate: date});

  } else if (view === 'day') {
    this.startDate = moment(date).startOf('day').toDate();
    this.endDate = moment(date).endOf('day').toDate();
    this.setState({ currentView: 'day' });
    this.setState({ selectedDate: date });
  }
  else if (view === 'week') {
    this.startDate = moment(date).startOf('week').toDate();
    this.endDate = moment(date).endOf('week').toDate();
    this.setState({ currentView: 'week' });
    this.setState({ selectedDate: date });
  }

  // console.log('startDate', this.startDate);
  // console.log('endDate', this.endDate);

  this.loadEvents();

}


In here I was able to use action and monitor the action.
onNavigate={(date, view, action) => {
    console.log('Navigation action:', action);
    if (action === 'DATE' || action === 'TODAY' || this.state.selectedDate !== date) {
      this.startDateCal(date, view, action);
    } else if (this.state.currentView !== view) {
      this.startDateCal(this.state.selectedDate, view, action);
    }
  }}

